# ServiceNow: Using Variable Condition field on custom tables

Tags: servicenow

I'm having a problem setting up a custom table with the Variable Conditions field type on ServiceNow to behave in the same way as it does on Catalog UI Policies.

I tried to emulate the the way it is set up on the Catalog UI Policy table. The field has 3 dependencies(catalog_item,variable_set,applies_to):

catalog_item: Reference to the catalog item

variable_set: Reference to a variable set

applies_to: String field with choice values 'item' and 'set'

I have set up my own table with these equivalent fields with different names and set up the dependencies in the same way yet the choice field and the 2 subsequent fields do not appear on the condition builder.

When clicking on the 'Add Filter Condition' button the following error message appears in a pop-up box: 'First Select a table'. Setting the variable conditions field to only have the catalog item dependency does allow the field to work without errors and im able to select a field but 'Keywords' is the only selectable one.

The error also appears when I extended the Catalog UI Policy table so obviously I'm missing something. I thought I might be missing something in business rules or client scripts but nothing stands out to me.

Any ideas how to get around this or what my next step should be?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I also did this some time ago, the only thing I had todo on my Custom Table was to create a field where I specify the Table for the Condition Builder and then select this field in the dictionary entry of the Condition Builder as Dependent Field.

[image]

and the result would like like this

[image]